# closing the Jquery mobile panel on submit button

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I have a jquery mobile panel like so:

```
<a href="#panel2"  class="ss-header-actions-language">
    <span class="ss-header-labels" id="ss-general-label">Language</span>
</a>

<div data-role = "panel" id = "panel2" data-display="overlay" data-position="right" data-swipe-close="false" >
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbEng1" AutoPostBack="true"   runat="server" Text="English"  GroupName="lang"   />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbspan1"  AutoPostBack="true"   runat="server" Text="Español"  GroupName="lang"   />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click"   />
</div>
```

I want the panel to close when the submit button is clicked. Right now, panel closes when I select any radio button inside the panel. I want the panel to stay open if the Radio button is clicked, but as soon as I click on submit button, I want the panel to close.

How can I achieve that. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to prevent postback to server, in order to do that set `AutoPostBack="false"` to `RadioButton` and you can change `asp:Button` to `input`.

Then according to [JQuery Mobile Panel](https://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/):

> A panel can also be closed by calling the panel's `close` method
> directly.

So this should work:

```
<a href="#panel2" class="ss-header-actions-language">
    <span class="ss-header-labels" id="ss-general-label">Language</span>
</a>

<div data-role="panel" id="panel2" data-display="overlay" data-position="right" data-swipe-close="false">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbEng1" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" Text="English" GroupName="lang" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbspan1" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" Text="Español" GroupName="lang" />
    <input type="button" onclick="ClosePanel();" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClosePanel() {
        $("#panel2").panel("close");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can I do this with autopostback=true for Radiobutton

Comment: Yes but you should work more on it. Because of with autopostback=true when you select radio button the page is post back and reload again, so in that case you should consider close panel in page load at client side.